# how to longPress in Appium 1.7?

Tags: appium-android

I am new to appium and using its version 1.7

i have to long press a webelement in my native app on android version 7.0
It shows all the methods are depreciated except for longPress(LongPressOptions longpressoptions) and longPress(PointOption longpressoptions).
so i started using it like below

I am using it like below

```
public static RemoteWebDriver driver;
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
WebElement homeScrSwipe = driver.findElementById("pulldown_image");
TouchAction ta = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
ta.longPress(homeScrSwipe, Duration.ofMillis(5000)).release().perform();
```

but it always gives me below error

The method longPress(WebElement, Duration) from the type TouchAction is deprecated.

If someone could let me know what is this longPressOptions in both the methods that would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
it may help you

```
        TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
        ta.longPress(x,y).moveTo(x,y).release().perform();
```

longPress(x,y) are Coordinates of mobile screen and moveTo(x,y) are to how many points you want swipe

for appium 1.7.1
android java client jar 5.0.4

Happy Testing

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));

    TouchAction Action = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
    // Action.longPress(webElement).perform();
    Action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void touchDown(MobileElement element) {
    new TouchAction(AppiumDriverCapabilitiesUtilities.driver).longPress(element2).release().perform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction(((MobileDriver) Driver));  
action1.longPress(LongPressOptions.longPressOptions().withElement(ElementOption.element(Element))).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500))).release();
```